# Make command not working for installing shairport

Tags: lubuntu, make, airplay

Here's the deal:
I'm trying to install Shairport for an Airplay server. I'm running the latest version of Lubuntu. I'm following [these directions](http://jordanburgess.com/post/38986434391/raspberry-pi-airplay) (meant for a RaspberryPi, but I don't see any reason why they shouldn't work for any linux system). After I download and compile Shairport, I'm supposed to run make (to build Shairport). However, it keeps returning this error:

```
make: *** [hairtunes] Error 1
```

I installed make, uninstalled it, reinstalled it, recompiled Shairport, and nothing works. Any ideas?

When I run make, here's the full text (pasting the text in here wasn't formatting right, so here's a screenshot): https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiLjr.png

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [tutorial](http://jordanburgess.com/post/38986434391/raspberry-pi-airplay) in your link said:

> Shairport has several prerequisites that need to be installed first.
> This is a single instruction to install them all:
>
> pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get install git libao-dev libssl-dev
> libcrypt-openssl-rsa-perl libio-socket-inet6-perl libwww-perl
> avahi-utils libmodule-build-perl

But the shairport [INSTALL.md](https://github.com/hendrikw82/shairport/blob/master/INSTALL.md) file says:

### Debian/Ubuntu:

> sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev
> libcrypt-openssl-rsa-perl libao-dev libio-socket-inet6-perl
> libwww-perl avahi-utils pkg-config

So, you can try to install all dependencies for shairport with:

- `sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libcrypt-openssl-rsa-perl libao-dev libio-socket-inet6-perl libwww-perl avahi-utils pkg-config`

Then you can compile shairport.

Comment: I think that helped. Now I'm getting an error that says `make: *** [shairport] Error 1`. So now shairport is in the brackets instead of hairtunes. Any suggestions?
Edit: I ignored the error and just started shairport. It works. Thanks!